# Cleaning up after block dismount

Tags: block-editor

I would like to do some actions when block is deleted from editor. I currently use this code:

```
    // cleanup of meta data from post, note that return value is cleanup function
    useEffect(() => () => {
            setMeta({ ...meta, term_definition: terms.filter(el => el.ID !== attributes.ID) });
            deleteEntityRecord('extra_table/v1', 'events_meta', events_meta_ID);
        }
    , []);
```

However, it seems that sometimes block variables (attributes and state - `events_meta_ID` is local state to block) are deleted before this code is run and therefore this code fails. Is there better way to do this - with one exception: I would not like to use class components instead of functions for block definition. So, no `componentWillUnmount()` solutions.

Comment: why are you wanting to do this? Creating and destroying posts like this is unusual and not what blocks are intended for ( also a class based component isn't compatible with modern block APIs such as `useBlockProps` ). There's an overwhelming chance that this approach is problematic and you should never have needed to do this in the first place

Comment: I am not creating and destroying posts this way. These are side effects. I create and destroy meta data (which are related to post) and data in another custom MySQL table. I have a block with innerblocks, which are related to this data. Each of these innerblocks can be created and destroyed and therefore their related data should be destroyed and created. I put this data in separate places (not in post content, but in separate tables) for performance reasons.

Comment: Since I have to filter and sort many posts according to dates of events. Each post can have many events. So I keep dates in a separate custom MySQL table, relationaly bounded to post (table has foreign key post_ID which is ID of the related post). Then in the special page I can show summaries of all posts filtered and sorted for certain dates, by using custom SQL query with INNER JOIN.

Comment: I know this is advanced and stretched using of Gutenberg, but it is certainly possible

Comment: I don't think the block is the place to do this, my suspicion is to do it via a subscriber to the relevant store on WP Data though I'm unclear on the details. Eitherway a good guide to think about this is that blocks and shortcodes are interchangeable ( albeit shortcodes are vastly inferior ), does it make sense that editing out a shortcode would cause a row in a table to be deleted? If not, then it doesn't make sense in a block either

Comment: if the meta is attached to the post not the block then it makes more sense that the data is merely shown in the block not added/deleted by it, and that the UI would exist in the posts sidebar as a panel, or in a plugin sidebar instead, so that you could list the meta with add/delete buttons and the block would be updated at the same time because it's `useEffect` and `useSelect` hooks would trigger a re-render

Comment: at which point, does it make sense that each meta is its own block and that adding a block creates an associated meta and removing it deletes it? I don't think so, not unless that block is purely for showing the meta, not _being_ the meta